# Design for a Logging module

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging, ssis

I'm working with few applications, Two Dot Net (Standalone Windows Thick client) and SSIS (SQL Server ETL Engine) and right now all of them use their own logging implementations. Dot Net uses Log4Net and SSIS writes to a text file.

I want to redesign this whole thing where all the applications right to one Logging interface. There are few options which I'm considering: Windows Event Logging, ELK(Elastic/LogStash) or [Custom Log provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/log-provider/creating-a-custom-log-provider?view=sql-server-2017)

Details:
It's a file processing system where we do a bunch of operations using DotNet Apps and then load the files, using SSIS, into a SQL server DB.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going for log4net in the other application. It is very popular, has lots of [features](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html), is maintained, well documented and you can find tons of help on it on different forums (including stackoverflow). It can do **much** more than just logging into a file. It supports remote logging, SMTP, .NET Trace, DB and even Windows Event Log. Allows for extremely flexible configuration.

It is always good to have separate logging for separate apps but you can have both log into a single logging target as well.